# Change hover color of <TextField /> in createMuiTheme()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

How do I change the `borderColor` on `hover` of the *outlined* `<TextField />` Component in the `createMuiTheme()`? Doing it for the underlined `<Input />` is rather easy

```
export default createMuiTheme({   
    MuiInput: {
        '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before': {
            borderBottom: '2px solid red',
        },
    }
});
```

But how do I access the *outlined* `<TextField />` Component (`variant='outlined'`).?

Generally: I really miss a good documentation on the `props` of the `JSON` passed to `createMuiTheme()`... Is there somewhere a place where I can see the whole object, with all possible/available props?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoever comes across this: I looked into the Github Repo of `Material UI`, at this file, lines 12-35.

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/OutlinedInput/OutlinedInput.js

I then changed it to

```
export default createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiOutlinedInput: {
            root: {
                '&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error) $notchedOutline': {
                borderColor: 'red',
            },
        },
      }
    }
});
```